# Solve transport equation with variable velocity $v(x,t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

I want to get the solution of
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}=v(x,t)\cdot \nabla u(x,t)$$
with $u(x,0)=f(x)$

The problem I encountered using method of characteristics is that: I cannot write the characteristics curve explicitly.

What I get is
$$u(x,t)=f(x+\int_0^t v(x,s)ds)$$
but it definitely should **not** be $v(x,s)$ in the integral. It should be independent of $x$, but I do not know how to express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbf{R}^d$ and $t \in [0, T]$. The characteristic equation is :
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}X'(s) &= -v(X(s), s)\\X(t) &= x.\end{aligned}\right.$$
By Cauchy-Lipschitz (if say $v$ is global lipschitz in $x$, uniformly in $t$) this equation has a unique solution $X(s; x, t)$. And the characteristic curve should be the curve :
$$\{(X(s;x,t), s) \colon s \in [0, T]\}.$$
The solution (if say $f$ is continuously differentiable) is given as you said by :
$$u(x, t) = f(X(0 ; x, t)).$$
The solution depends on $X$ which you get by solving the characteristic equation first, it does not have a closed form like $x + \int_0^t v(x, -)$.

Take for example $v$ to be constant. Then the characteristic equation is solved as $X(s;x,t) = x + (t-s)v$ and you get $u(x, t) = f(x + tv)$. Your formula works here.

But take another example, say $v(x, t) = -x$. Then the characteristic equation is solved as $X(s;x,t) = x\mathrm{e}^{s-t}$, which yields $u(x, t) =  f(x\mathrm{e}^{-t})$ which is not of the form you gave.